# Magento, addAttributeToSelect, alias

Tags: magento, collections

how to make an alias (AS) when using collections.

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('total_qty')
```

It can be done this way:

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('alias'=>'total_qty'))
```

but then I will get both "total_qty" and "total_qty AS alias", in the query.

Comment: I managed to do it this way:

    $collection->getSelect()
               ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)      
               ->columns(array('alias' => 'total_qty'...

Answer (score 4):

If you collection is an instance of `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` then you can use the function `addFieldToSelect`.

This function takes two attributes. Firstly it takes the field you want to add to the select and secondly it takes an alias.

```
public function addFieldToSelect($field, $alias = null)
```